# Ember data: findRecord is undefined. (also peekRecord or peekAll)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to switch to ember-data and I cant seem to find a solution to this error:

TypeError: this.store.findRecord is not a function. (In 'this.store.findRecord('feed', feed_id)', 'this.store.findRecord' is undefined)

This is my code inside the controller as an action:

```
    toggleArchive(feed_id, param,intercom_event){
        var self = this;
        this.set('isLoading',true);

        return this.store.findRecord('feed', feed_id).then(function(feed) {
            //Setting the system_status of the feed to either 4 (archived) or 1 (normal)
            feed.set('system_status',param);
            //Persist to change to store (and server)
            return feed.save();
        });
    },
```

On the route I call :

```
model: function(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('feed',params.feed_id);
},
```

And in package.json im using : "ember-data": "1.13.8",

If I call the old `this.store.find()` method, the record is retrieved, but this is not ideal as the method is being deprecated and I doesn't work as expected.

Any hints on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `toggleArchive`?

Comment: Calling `this.store.XXX` inside `toggleArchive` won't work. You will need to redefine `var self = this` outside that function to avoid shadowing it.

Comment: Weirdly enough, the find() method is working perfectly. But I need findRecord to work.

Comment: toggleArchive is inside an action in the Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need package entry for Ember Data in bower.json:

```
"ember-data": "1.13.8"
```